# dynamically change imageview

Tags: dynamic, imageview, drawable

I have an image for each of 6 weather conditions. I have an imageView setup. I want to change that dynamically.

I have tried so many examples and none work. I think something about drawable has been depreciated. Any ideas?

I have string str with the filename in it. Thats as far as I got.

One thing I have tried

```
    int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(str, "drawable", getPackageName());
```

ImageView conditions = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cloudView);
conditions.setImageResource(resID );

Comment: What Language, What library, what did you tried? Eveyrthing in your question is missing.

Comment: Java and android.widget.ImageView

Comment: Example, I tried this where str was the name of the file in the drawable folder

int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(str, "drawable", getPackageName());

ImageView conditions = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cloudView);;

conditions.setImageResource(resID );